# How to grab first line of string and display in php?

Tags: php

Below is my code:

```
<?php 
 $array = explode("\n", $order['payment_address']);
 $firstLine = $array[0];
 echo $firstLine;
 ?>
```

What i am trying to do is grab the name of customer in first line from $order['payment_address'] and print it. Payment_address includes several lines with customer name on top. Tried the code by Ben Pearl Kahan and output is now as -

Bob Smith
12

Line 1: Bob Smith
12
Line 2: Kannaught Place
Delhi 282010
Uttar Pradesh
India

While i want just "Bob Smith".

I am a novice. Plz help.

Comment: provide output of array $order['payment_address']

Comment: Here was the output - Bob Smith 12, Kannaught Place Delhi 282010 Uttar Pradesh India demo@demo.com 9999999999

Comment: Try `$firstLine = preg_split('~<br */?>|\R~i', $order['payment_address'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)[0];` would that do it? Maybe you have html `<br>`

Comment: Hi bobble bubble, it worked. Many many thanks. Please do show this code in answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: Welcome. So you had `<br>` line breaks, it seems :p You need to [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) if not sure about what's inside your variables eg if you view in browser: `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($order['payment_address']); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Thanks, i am editing invoice of Opencart and just want the name to declare a statement for customer by designating his/her name, and in browser its displaying good. Thx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure about what's inside your variable, always [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). To view in browser

```
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($order['payment_address']); echo '</pre>';
```

The following [regex would split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) at any linebreak-sequence or `<br>` and return first non empty item.

```
$firstLine = preg_split('~<br */?>|\R~i', $order['payment_address'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)[0];
```

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/524642)

Answer (score 0):

Without providing output of `$order["payment_address"]`, this should help:

```
//Trim whitespace from start/end of string
$pa = trim($order["payment_address"]);

//Check if the value is empty
if(!empty($pa)){

    //Explode by line
    $array = explode("\n", $pa);

    //Echo out first line
    echo "First line: {$array[0]}<br><br>";

    //See data line-by-line
    $num = 0;
    foreach($array as $line){
        $num++;
        echo "Line $num: $line<br>";
    }        

} else echo "Payment address is empty!<br>"; //Output error if $pa is empty
```

---

For comma-separated values:

```
//Trim whitespace from start/end of string
$pa = trim($order["payment_address"]);

//Check if the value is empty
if(!empty($pa)){

    //Explode by line
    $array = explode(", ", $pa);

    //Echo out first line
    echo "First line: {$array[0]}<br><br>";

    //See data line-by-line
    $num = 0;
    foreach($array as $line){
        $num++;
        echo "Line $num: $line<br>";
    }        

} else echo "Payment address is empty!<br>"; //Output error if $pa is empty
```

Comment: Here was the output -                                                                          Bob Smith
12, Kannaught Place
Delhi 282010
Uttar Pradesh
India
demo@demo.com
9999999999

Comment: @AnkurSaraswat The output of what? That doesn't look like the output from my answer!

Comment: First line: Bob Smith
12, Kannaught Place
Delhi 282010
Uttar Pradesh
India

Line 1: Bob Smith
12, Kannaught Place
Delhi 282010
Uttar Pradesh
India

Comment: First line: Bob Smith
12

Line 1: Bob Smith
12
Line 2: Kannaught Place
Delhi 282010
Uttar Pradesh
India           Not working sir.